# Illustrator: noting fonts before creating outlines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

Is there a way to keep a 'virtual notebook' of a file so I can remember which fonts I used after I've created outlines? I really like fonts and have far too many, so it's hard to remember which one I used.

Comment: My usual advice is to not outline fonts at all. And if you (think you) *must* ... copy the layer with the text and hide it. You never know when a typo pops up.

Comment: So what are you actually asking? Are you looking for a list of all fonts used in a single project? Just use a package report.

Comment: Don't outline the fonts in your original AI file.  Never ever overwrite that file. It's your original artwork!  If you really must convert fonts to outlines, then save  the resulting document with a different file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also wondered about this while making proposals for logos, trying out different fonts then converting to outlines so I can play with the object box better or adjust the lettering.

What I do is actually make notes outside the artboard so I always know which version was set in which typeface. These are just drafts ofcourse and I will also keep editable versions on the other side of the artboard, so if the client requires other edits I can easily go back to the non-converted text.

When the client approves the work and commits to purchase the selected typefaces, I will usually clean up all the in-between versions and just keep a single AI file with both converted and editable name, or in many cases just the converted version.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this following script to add a note in the Attribute > notes after outlining. The procedure is that this script creates the outlines for you, so in order to create the outlines you've got to use this script & not manual shortcuts, etc.

```
#target illustrator
function test(){
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  var sel = doc.selection[0];
  var textFontName = sel.characters[0].characterAttributes.textFont.name;
  var newGroup = sel.createOutline();
  newGroup.note = textFontName;
}
test();
```

The important parts are to have a document open and to have a selection that is text (the live kind), before running the script. Also, it takes the font name from the very first character on the assumption that all of your text is the same font. If you have different fonts, it'll take some more work and will depend on your particular requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is. I would just duplicate the text, hide the layer that isn't outlined.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor the question is asking how the user can remember what the font is when it is outlined. I am saying there is no default way that Illustrator remembers what the font is when outlined. My suggestion is to duplicate the original text so one is outlined and one is not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden layer or many of them with all kind of markings and explanations, as rich as it is needed to be able to recall the used tricks and ingredients.

Note: essentially this is the same as user Lucian already has suggested.